# IIS URL Rewrite To Capture Query Strings

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to redirect http://example.com/auth/recover?u=123&t=456 to http://example.com/#!/passwordreset/123/456

My URL config looks like.

```
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect Forgotten Password" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^auth/recover" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="u=([0-9]+)" />
              <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="t=([0-9]+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/#!/resetpassword/{C:0}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

Unfortunately when the rewrite happens I end up with a URL that looks like : http://example.com/#!/resetpassword/u=123/123

If I swap the conditions around, I get a similar thing happening (I get a t=456 in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason it doesn't work, and a way around it so I'm going to answer my own answer here.

It seems that when using conditions in IIS rewrites, only the LAST condition will be passed to the redirect action. It also seems like {C:0} will match the entire condition, and then the indexes after that are the matching expressions within that condition.

One way would be to create a single condition that would match the query string all in one lot. But that means that your params in your query string would have to be in the same order everytime.

Instead I did the following :

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect Forgotten Password" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^auth/recover" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="u=([0-9]+)" />
          <add input="##{C:1}##_{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="##([^#]+)##_.*t=([0-9]+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/#!/resetpassword/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So it matches the first condition I want, then passes it to the next condition to be "rematched" again along with my second param. Not that elegant, but it works!